# retrofit and orm library throw StackOverflow

Tags: android, orm, gson, retrofit, sugarorm

I try to use 2 libraries:

- square/Retrofit - Rest client
- satyan/sugar - db orm

*retrofit* use *gson*, so do class

```
public class Book{
    String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

ok, retrofit succesfully get data from server and put in our Book class.

now i want save this data. for use orm need `extend` parent class

```
    public class Book extends SugarRecord<Book>{
    String name;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

but after extend the parent class, retrofit cannot parse json.

so we get an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
...
Caused by: retrofit.RetrofitError: java.lang.StackOverflowError at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:390)
...
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError at  com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types.resolve($Gson$Types.java:375)
...
```

how to make friends 2 libraries that they use one object class?

or how to specify the retrofit, so that it did not touch Book's class parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error happens when Gson tries to resolve type information about an object it have to deserialize. It gets into an infinite recursion due to the cyclic reference to your `Book` class in `extends` declaration.

However even if Gson could cope with your class, I would not recommend using these libs combination.

You see, what Gson does is much alike to what standard Java serialization does but in JSON format. I mean that Gson takes the internal state of your object and performs its serialization. And when it parses JSON it creates an object with the state specified in this JSON.

If you take a look at `SugarRecord` class, you'll see that it has a field named "tableName". Thus if you passed your `Book` object to `Gson` instance, you'd get

`{name: "book name", tableName: "table_book"}`.

Moreover, if you got a response from server which is like

`{name: "another book name", tableName: "something absolutely unrelated"}`,

you would get an instance of `Book` with a state exactly matching what is described in this response. Meaning, with `tableName` being not equal to what you would like...

You could workaround this issue using [exclusion strategies](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization) in Gson, but overall you'll get yet another problem.

P.S. After a quick look at [`SugarRecord`](https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/com/orm/SugarRecord.java) class on github I do not understand why it has a type parameter at all. It's even not used really. Thus technically I think you'll be able to combine these 2 libraries, if you skip type parameter in `extends` declaration making your  class look like `class Book extends SugarRecod { }`, and use an [exclusion strategy](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Excluding-Fields-From-Serialization-and-Deserialization). Yet, I wouldn't do it myself in practice :).

Comment: I like the retrofit, and to avoid the problems I'm willing to use another orm library. but any ORM require inherit their class. What do you advise?

Comment: Well, I'm not an active ORM libraries user, thus I cannot advise. But I believe there is one that leverages annotations instead of making it necessary to inherit some class.

Comment: Maybe you can get the parsed fields in a callback and then save it with sugar by having a different class for ORM? Only bad part about this is that db insertion will be happening on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Your POJO class need  a empty constructor :

you shoud add this constructor to your Book class:

```
public Book(){

}
```