# Retrofit + GSON + ORM

Tags: android, orm, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit + GSON in my app and till now I have been writing raw sql queries to communicate with the database. It is proving to be a time consuming task and I have started looking at ORM libraries that I can use.

[GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) seems to the fastest but as it generates the model classes all the custom GSON annotations will have to entered every time there is a change in the model class.

[Sugar ORM](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/) also seems to have some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014735/retrofit-and-orm-library-throw-stackoverflow) working well as a combo

Are there any ORMs that play well with GSON or should I start using 2 different types of classes: one for db model & one for retrofit + gson?

Answer (score 0):

the one that works for me is Cupboard http://code.neenbedankt.com/introducing-cupboard-simple-persistance-for-android/
for reference.

Comment: You should provide a short summary of what is been found under the link you posted. Link-only is discouraged here.

Comment: I have moved to a combination of Retrofit + Jackson + ORMlite and it works great. ORMlite looked more developer friendly and powerful than Cupboard when I compared them