# Retrofit StackOverFlow

Tags: java, retrofit, stack-overflow, okhttp

I'am trying to do a login using Retrofit and OkHttp and I get the StackOverflowError.

```
private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    .create();

private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("User-Agent", UserAgent);
        request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    }
};

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

RestAdapter restApdter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(API_PATH)
    .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
    .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
    .build();

service = restApdter.create(UserService.class);
service.loginUser(jUser, new Callback<User>() {
@Override
public void success(User user, Response response) {               
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {                
}
});
```

Someone knows why I get this error?
Thanks for help

Comment: @MillieSmith To be honest, no.

Comment: It would be easier if you could provide more details about the error (stacktrace).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you have the same problem as this guy:
[retrofit and orm library throw StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014735/retrofit-and-orm-library-throw-stackoverflow)

Does the User class you use extend a model class of an ORM by any chance?
If that's the case one solution is to duplicate your class and use one for serializing and other one for database writing.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote  boilderplate code for Retrofit with OkHttp
https://github.com/saleeh93/APIservice-Sample/